# How to extract particular lines in text file using heading in python and return it in function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to extract particular information from text file using headings in the file.There are different headings and corresponding content for each heading.I need to extract content from particular heading and return it in function.I tried lot of ways but not able to achieve

```
Here is the description of file:

    INTERFACE 2: XYZ =====================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
    INTERFACE 2, 1: ABC ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x2
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x1
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
      ENDPOINT 0x1: Isochronous ========================
       bLength          :    0x9 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x1 OUT
```

I need to extract these information like ABC content , XYZ content but not able to extract that.

My question is as below:
1) How we will extract content with particular heading and how to return it in some function ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is what you want, but this will give you a dictionary with headings and content:

```
content_dict = dict()
heading_line = None
for l in f.readlines():
    # recognize heading lines
    if "======" in l:  # if this doesn't cover, you might need to define a regex
        heading_line = l
        content_dict[heading_line] = dict()
    else:
        field_name = l.split(':')[0].strip()
        field_val = l.split(':')[1].strip()
        content_dict[heading_line][field_name] = field_val
```

using the content_dict above, for each heading you have a dict of the fields string values. If you want you could extract from them whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!!. It really helped but problem with this logic is I am only able to get output of  ENDPOINT 0x1: Isochronous heading .How to get output of each field like INTERFACE 2: XYZ content and INTERFACE 2, 1: ABC  ?

Comment: Thanks for your edit!!!. But it still didn't solve the problem I am not able to extract particular data according to the heading.